# How to differentiate two distinct linear populations with clustering in R

Tags: r, clustering, model-based-clustering

I am new to clustering.  My apology if this has been asked before.

I'd like to differentiate two distinct linear populations within sample matrix, and tag them differently.  Apparently k-means couldn't do a good job, which is shown in the plot below.  Does anybody have any good suggestion?

Example code:

```
x <- c(1:1000)
y <- x
y2 <- 10 * x
sample <- matrix(c(x, x, y, y2), nrow = 2000)
```

[image]

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thank Imo.  I'll post it over there.  I thought the sample size & data type are there in the sample code...

Comment: If you wait a minute this question will be migrated over there. I assumed you were just presenting an example rather than the full dataset you are working with.

Answer (score 0):

It might be because this data does not contain any actual clusters.

```
plot(x,y2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Bryan. The sample matrix actually shows something different.